# Permissions to delete generated files from another user in linux (gitlab-runner)

Tags: linux, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Im using gitlab-runner to deploy my php application to nginx web server.
To deploy im using this steps:
1. delete all files in folder /var/www/site
2. move files from gitlab repository to /var/www/site

All these actions are performed only after pushing to repository new changes.

I have a problem. Files that copied to /var/www/site owned by gitlab-runner.
After uploading file from post form, files owned by www-data (nginx user).
After next push, gitlab cant deploy because it's failed on first step. user gitlab-runner hasn't right to delete www-data files.

I cant change nginx user to gitlab-runner for a reason, and i don't know how to change gitlab-runner to another user.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command chown to change the owner of a file.

chmod uu:gg  will set the owner of the file to uu and the group to gg.

You can change permissions of a file with chmod command.

chmod g+w  will give write access to file to users of the group of

With this commands you should be able to set the group of the files to a group compatible with git-lab (check initial group of files with ls -l command)

Comment: The problem is that i need to use chmod right after nginx saves uploaded file, how can i do this? user gitlab-runner hasn't permission to use chmod on this files

Comment: Maybe you can try chmod g+s on the directory containg uploaded files and guve the directory the correct group for gitlab-runner.